# Select from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

[image: Table Structure]

I'm selecting from LOG_TABLE `user_id` `changes` but when selecting I want `user_id` to correspond `username`in USER_NAME table where id's of LOG_TABLE and USER_TABLE match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll provide an additional answer here, since you are just starting out.  This INNER JOIN code will select every row from LOG_TABLE that has a match in USER_TABLE.

```
SELECT l.id, l.changes, u.username
FROM LOG_TABLE l
INNER JOIN USER_TABLE u ON u.id = l.user_id
```

If you wanted to SELECT from LOG_TABLE, but really didn't care if it has a match in USER_TABLE or not, you could do a LEFT JOIN instead:

```
SELECT l.id, l.changes, u.username
FROM LOG_TABLE l
LEFT JOIN USER_TABLE u ON u.id = l.user_id
```

When writing a JOIN, it is always a good idea to explicitly state your JOIN keywords and conditions.  If you use an implicit JOIN (tables listed after the FROM clause, separated by a comma), you run the risk of producing a Cartesian Product if your WHERE clause is accidentally omitted.

Case-in-point, here is a question where the OP has used the comma-separated JOIN notation, and inadvertently created a Cartesian Product: [MySQL Query - Join Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457079/mysql-query-join-issues)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a JOIN. Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html For this specific example, something like this is what you want:

```
SELECT l.changes, u.username
FROM LOG_TABLE l, USER_TABLE u
WHERE u.id=l.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l.changes, u.username
FROM LOG_TABLE l
JOIN USER_TABLE u on u.id=l.user_id
```